# Theme takes different css file from /default/files/css when uploaded to remote server from local

Tags: theming, 8

I have zymphonies theme installed in my Drupal 8 website. In my localhost everything was working fine. But when I uploaded the entire files to the remote server the styling of breadcrumbs has gone (it shows as numbered list). As I inspected with the firebug the css file that is taken from default/files/css is different.

There are large number of css files in the default/files/css how does Drupal choose to select a particular css from that set of css files?

Answer (score 2):

The location "*default/files/css*" is used to store aggregated CSS files, created by Drupal Core. CSS/JS file aggregation can be enabled/disabled by navigating to *Drupal Performance* settings page, using "***Admin => Configure => Development => Performance***" and enabling checkbox "***Aggregate CSS files***". You can also delete the *.css* files from "*default/files/css*" directory and Drupal will automatically create new one whenever site is visited first time after that. Check the screenshot below:

[image: Drupal Performance Settings]

It is not advisable on production, but if you want to use original files from Theme's CSS directory directly, then uncheck "**Aggregate CSS files**" setting checkbox and Try clearing cache.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did as you mentioned and cleared all the caches. But still the breadcrumb style is different from what is showing in my local system. I have made sure that themes/theme_name/css/global.css is same in both my local and remote.

Comment: Ok, Check your page view source (`ctrl+u`) and try accessing `global.css` file in browser to make sure the breadcrumb CSS is available. If not try refreshing few times or try in incognito window.

Comment: Ok, in that case, you might need to check template and if required override remote template.

Comment: I have inspected the code and found the rendered template is slightly different each other. The original breadcrumb is rendered as unordered list (within <ul> ) and there is a 'breadcrumb-divider' after each list items. But in the remote server the breadcrumbs are rendered as ordered list and the breadcrumb-divider is also missing

Comment: Check if your site theme, if it is overriding breadcrumb HTML. This should mostly be inside 'THEME_NAME.theme' file, but check other files as well. The best possible way to search is search using class name "breadcrumb-divider" in entire theme.

Comment: There is a theme override for breadcrumb inside theme_name/template/navigation/breadcrumb.html.twig.  When I reanamed this file everything is working as it is supposed to be. So temporarily the issue is fixed, but the file exist in the both cases so I don’t understand is what triggeres this override to be active. Thanks for the valuable input Yogesh.